# problem of version of java while opening the IDE eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

everytime I try to open the app "eclipse IDE" on my windows 10 laptop, I have an error message which is saying that :"version 1.8.0_381" of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 17 or greater is required"

I am sure that I already installed a version of JAVA which is greater than version 17, I don't Understand the problem, when I re-install eclipse, it works great and I find all the work I ve done on it, but if I turn off my computer, the same problem reapears at the next turning-on

Comment: You should check your "Java_Home" field in your environment variables